# Pass a Object back to jsp file from Controller in SpringMVC

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my application I want to pass a object back to the jsp file using ajax.

**JSP file**

```
function getval(sel) {
            jq(function() {
                jq.post("/spring-mvc-jquery/krams/main/ajax/add", {
                    inputNumber3 : jq(sel).val()
                }, function(data) {
                    alert(data.getName);
                });
            });
        }
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Person view(@RequestParam(value = "inputNumber3", required = true) Integer inputNumber3) {

        logger.debug("Input number recieved: " + inputNumber3);
        return new Person("John", 22);
    }
```

But in the allertbox i cant get the Person's object values. In the code I want to see the alertbox showing `John`. But it shows 'unspecified'. If I return a int value(25) instead of person object, it shows successfully.

Please help. **Answers in the other questions didn't help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `alert(data.name);` instead. You can check what's actually returned from browser debug e.g. press F12 in Chrome and set a breakpoint in the JS.

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked. means we don;t have to use getters, setters. directly use the variable name.